# TYPO3: Set more than one storage pid for one extension

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I builded an extension that has a 'details' table that holds details with a title and a description that be included inline to another object. Right now new details are stored in the same pid as the object, but I'd like to change that.

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141992/change-storage-pid-when-programmatically-persisting-a-model) was answered by [Merec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2110794/merec) and in the comments he points to a solution (add the column "pid" to your model, this is the first the model looks at) but asked to formulate a separate question for it ...

I took his suggestion but could not get it to work, **so here is the separate question**, in addition I would like to know how to get a value from the configuration to be used as pid for this.

**update:** René Pflamm pointed out that I should underline that I'm trying to set this Pid for **saving in the backend**, not in the frontend ... I basically recognized this destinction later on

my constants.ts :

```
plugin.tx_myext {
  persistence {
    # cat=plugin.tx_myext/storage/a; type=string; label=Default storage PID
    defaultStoragePid =
    # cat=plugin.tx_myext/storage/a; type=string; label=Details storage PID
    detailsStoragePid =
  }
}
```

my setup.ts

```
plugin.tx_myext {
  persistence {
    storagePid = {$plugin.tx_myext.persistence.defaultStoragePid}
    detailPid = {$plugin.tx_myext.persistence.detailsStoragePid}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if I understood you correctly but you can tell extbase to look in multiple pids for your records and state for each record where it should be stored:

```
plugin.tx_myext {
  persistence {
    storagePid = {$plugin.tx_myext.persistence.defaultStoragePid},{$plugin.tx_myext.persistence.detailStoragePid}
    classes {
      Vendor\MyExt\Domain\Model\Detail {
        newRecordStoragePid = {$plugin.tx_myext.persistence.detailStoragePid}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks just right, any other pointers how to debug? I can't get it to work ... tx_myext was named originally tx_myext_objects by the builder but changing that did not affect the other settings (and I tried to set it back without result for the newRecordStoragePid), the snippet you give is setup.ts is it not ?

Comment: if I'd use config. or module. instead of plugin. ? still trying to get it to work

Comment: what about saving in the backend?

Answer (score 2):

Models inherits from `TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractDomainObject` which has getter and setter for `$pid`. If you set the field, all automation to set the field (i.e. newRecordStoragePid in typoscript) are not used.

With this, you can set all storage locations you want.

```php
$myModel = $this->objectManager->create('Vendor\\Namespace\\Domain\\Model\\MyModel');
$myModel->setPid(4321);
```

Part from `TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\DomainObject\AbstractDomainObject`:

```
/**
 * @var int The id of the page the record is "stored".
 */
protected $pid;

/**
 * Setter for the pid.
 *
 * @param int|NULL $pid
 * @return void
 */
public function setPid($pid)
{
    if ($pid === null) {
        $this->pid = null;
    } else {
        $this->pid = (int)$pid;
    }
}

/**
 * Getter for the pid.
 *
 * @return int The pid or NULL if none set yet.
 */
public function getPid()
{
    if ($this->pid === null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return (int)$this->pid;
    }
}
```

Comment: where would I set it ? the details table which should store in a separate pid is NOT aggregate root, standard from the extension builder I have only a model for this table ... (sorry I'm not that handy with php classes and typo3 yet)

Comment: the "aggregate root" option in the extension builder just specifies, if a controller and repository will be generated upon save. You can manually create a respository class for each model. Copy and paste it from the other aggregate root (if there is one set) or check out the extbase documentation.

Comment: `$myModel = $this->objectManager->create('Vendor\\Namespace\\Domain\\Model\\MyModel');
$myModel->setPid(4321);` should be added to DetailsRepository.php ?, maybe very stupid question but I do not recognize this syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can, when create elements in your extension, say the model which pid should be use.

In your TS:

```
plugin.tx_myext.settings {
  detailPid = {$plugin.tx_myext.persistence.detailsStoragePid}
}
```

In your code above it can look like:

```
public function createDetailsAction(Detail $detail) {
  $detail->setPid($this->settings['detailPid']);
  $this->detailRepository->add($detail);
}
```

Comment: In which class would I put this snippet ? Details is not aggregate root, I've only a model Details.php ...

Comment: In an controller where you create your details.

Comment: thank you 4 the attention, if you build with extension builder there is no controller nor a repository for the details so there is no call for create, I did create them but I get no result ...

Comment: it looks as if it should be in the controller, does that not only affect the front-end action ?

Comment: That's right. For the backend I don't have any ideas how to solve it.

Comment: thank you, I think that one of the brains will help me to find it, then it will be available here ...

Comment: I think you should highlight this information in the main thread. No body will think that you want this for backend.